# Ajax call not working in attrvalidate jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation

I want to add ajax call in the attrvalidate jquery plugin.
But i'm confused that where i should add my ajax call in the below code.
..

[Enter here to see code](https://github.com/fraddski/attrvalidate/blob/master/attrvalidate.jquery.js)

Comment: @JaromandaX
lolz!.
I am surprized to read your comment.
 If i am going to implement ajax call after validation then according to you, what should i do next !.
Obviously i will send this form into database .
...

Comment: lolz !
Wow !
What an idea you gave !
THanx buddy !

Comment: I have checked that out before.
I'm not expert in JavaScript that's why posted my question here..
..
But i think, here nobody knows that what to do ...
...
Anyways, thanks for your time !
..
Still if you finds any solution, do share that with me.

Comment: Oh my dear, Oh my dear, Oh my dear, Oh my dear, Oh my dear,  I have told you round about 100 of times before that i want to send my form in database using ajax..
...
Don't you got someones' point soon ?